# Unit testing firebase admin SDK authentication on node.JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs, firebase-admin

Is there any way I can write unit tests for firebase authentication to store locally? I want to do something like mongodb-memory-server, so all the data saved doesn't persists when the tests are over. I want to create some tests to those two functions specifically:

```
async function createResearcherOnFirebase(email, password) {
  return admin.auth().createUser({
    email,
    password,
  }).then((researcherRecord) => researcherRecord.uid).catch(() => false);
}


async function grantResearcherRole(uid) {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { researcher: true })
    .then(() => true).catch(() => false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While for some Firebase products there is now an [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) that you can run locally for precisely such use-cases, Firebase Authentication is currently not in there.

If you don't want to hit the real project, you will have to mock the service and inject it.

Comment: How can I mock it? I'm kinda new to firebase.

Comment: I don't know much about Jest, but it seems like there are some popular approaches: https://www.google.com/search?q=jest+mock